# Exception on app startup in device,works fine in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash

The application works fine on the simulator but breaks in start up in device as in the figure

[image]

I tried some of the solution in SO but It doesnt work out.What may be the reason ?How can i find it? How to resolve it

For clarity

[image]

Tried : Changing the view controller the viewcontroller. view did load and all functions are working fine after that when the view tries to appear on the screen the crash appears

UPDATE : Now getting the error logged as

```
*** -[Not A Type retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x208c9610
```

Comment: Please post some code where crash occur.

Comment: This is what that occour ,No code pointed by this error

Comment: Add exception breakpoint that may give you where it crashed.

Comment: tried that also,But this is what it shows.

Comment: Check the spelling of XIB file, its Case sensitive, any change means some times working in simulator but Crash in device.

Comment: @SibaPrasadHota : all names cross checked It is correct.

Comment: try to enable Guard Edges,Guard Malloc, Zombie objects , malloc stack and stop on Debugger() and DebugStr().
hopefully these will help you in figuring out crashing point.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before. This is not a crash. Please remove all your break points and run it again.

Comment: @LithuT.V: are you still using MRC ? Check the code where you are calling `retain`

Comment: Yeah i use retain.Is it the problem?

Comment: @LithuT.V: Yeah, then check those retain calls. MRC- Manual Reference Counting. I prefer ARC, try to use it, it'll reduce most of your issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **Breakpoint** error ..... It normally occurs when you add a breakpoint to an app running in the device. If you add the breakpoints before the app has been built and run it again.... The crash will not occur.

Even I couldn't figure out why this crash should occur in the first place but it does.

Answer (score 0):

OK found out the problem.I am using an external library which does not implement ARC so it has to be flagged.all files except 2 are not flagged as `-fno-objc-arc` and hence the issue.